# How to git clone a project to the root directory (/)?

Tags: git

I have a project with some folders that should be in the root directory like:

```
/etc
/run
/tmp
```

And if possible, I want to clone that project right to the root directory so that I don't have to move those folders manually, is it possible to do that? I tried:

```
git clone myprojecturl /
```

but it gave me:

```
fatal: destination path '/' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: `git clone` is for cloning an entire repository structure to some location on your computer.  The error message is complaining the target directory is not empty.  Typically, the way to move folders is to just move them.  You can do this using or not using Git commands, either should work.

Comment: You really should not do this. A `git checkout` has the potential of removing files your computer needs, and a `git clean` would probably be catastrophic to your system. Why do you think you need to version **your entire operating system**?

Answer (score 1):

Taking `/etc` for example, simulate `git clone`:

```
cd /etc
git init
git remote add origin <remote-repo-url>
git fetch
git checkout <branch>
```

There may be some permission issues. I don't think it's proper to make `/etc` a git repository. There are many other foders and files in it. It could bring unexpected troubles.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone [repository] [local path]
```

If your working directory is your desired destination, simply put a .

```
$ git clone git@repo-site.com .
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clone use pull. I.e., create a git repo at the root FS:

```
cd /
git init .
git pull myprojecturl
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put symlinks in the system directories that point into your Git repo. However, it is usually safer to write an install script to update system files.